# How to do advanced ASP.NET MVC (3) routes (computed actions, etc.)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

**UPDATED**

Considering the following 8 routes where `Administration` is **area**, **controller** is `EmployeesController` and **Id** is `EmployeeId`:

1. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Phones/{PhoneId}/Delete`

   - action = `DeletePhone`
2. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Phones/{PhoneId}/Deactivate`

   - action = `DeactivatePhone`
3. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Phones/{PhoneId}/Activate`

   - action = `ActivatePhone`
4. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Notes/{NoteId}/Delete`

   - action = `DeleteNote`
5. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Files/{FileId}/Delete`

   - action = `DeleteFile`
6. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Addresses/{AddressId}/Delete`

   - action = `DeleteAddress`
7. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Addresses/{AddressId}/Deactivate`

   - action = `DeactivateAddress`
8. `Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/Addresses/{AddressId}/Activate`

   - action = `ActivateAddress`

How can I transform it into:

`Administration/Corporate/{controller}/{Id}/{object}/{ObjectId}/{action}` where **object** is `Phones|Notes|Files|Addresses|?` and **action** is `Delete|Deactivate|Activate|?`?

1. I need to take **object** and singularize it (for which I already have the code).

   - object = `Phones` (`Phone`)
2. Take **action** and transform (rewrite?) it into **action** + **object** (singularized).

   - action = `Delete`+`Phone` (`DeletePhone`)

I can do everything up to the second #2 where the issue is how can I transform the action into something else *in the route definition*?

Is any of this even possible at all? It would be nice to take the 8 routes I have now and turn them into 1. And this example only uses my `EmployeesController`, my `CustomersController` is twice that size so about 16 routes that can be turned into 1. It would save a lot of space and code.

Anyway, I'm looking forward to suggestions and ideas if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom route handler.

```
public class CustomRoute : RouteBase
{
    //your custom code
}
```

[ASP.NET MVC Subdomain Routing](http://hanssens.org/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx/)

Comment: I love the ominous empty body.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a simple array and method to handle this kind of thing. Its not exactly elegant, but it should be easy to understand:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes()
{
    var adminRoutes = new[]
                            {
                                new [] { "Phones", "PhoneId", "Delete", "DeletePhone" },
                                // Add the rest of your routes here.
                            };

    foreach ( var adminRoute in adminRoutes )
    {
        RegisterAdminRoute( adminRoute[0], adminRoute[1], adminRoute[2], adminRoute[3] );
    }
}

public static void RegisterAdminRoute( string area, string idName, string actionName, string action )
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute
        (
            area + actionName,
            String.Format( "Administration/Corporate/{{controller}}/{{Id}}/{0}/{{{1}}}/{2}",
                            area,
                            idName,
                            actionName ),
            new { action }
        );
}
```